# What does "let $f\left(z\right)=\bar{z}$" mean in this context

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm reading a paper/handout on contour integrals and Cauchy's Theorem which says in an example

> Let $f\left(z\right)=\bar{z}$.
>
> $\cdots$
>
> Then \begin{align}
>  \int_{C}\bar{z}\:dz&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\overline{e^{it}}\cdot
>  ie^{it}\:dt\\ &=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}\cdot ie^{it}\:dt\\
>  &=\int_0^{2\pi} i\:dt\\ &=2\pi i. \end{align}

What is this operation "$\overline{e^{it}}=e^{-it}$"? Please let me know if it appears I have not given enough context. I've looked over the document and do not see it mentioned though, so I am assuming it is something from complex analysis I have not seen (I haven't taken that class yet).

Comment: Complex conjugation. It's introduced before contour integrals in complex analysis. I recommend you convince yourself $\overline{e^{it}}=e^{-it}$ is a true statement.

Comment: $\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate of the complex variable $z$.

Comment: @anon Thanks! Case closed.

Comment: It is just complex conjugation, the simplest example of antiholomorphic function

Comment: @anon I find that \begin{align}e^{it}\cdot ie^{-it}&=i e^{\left(i+-i\right)t}\\&=i.\end{align} Therefore \begin{align}\int_C\bar{z}\:dz&=\int_0^{2\pi}i\overline{e^{it}}e^{it}\:dt\\&=\int_0^{2\pi}ie^{\left(i+-i\right)t}\:dt\\&=it\bigg|_0^{2\pi}\\&=2\pi i.\end{align} It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notation is [complex conjugation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate). For a complex number $z=a+bi$, the complex conjugate of $z$ is defined to be
$$\overline{z} := a-bi$$

Answer (score 1):

It is the [complex conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate). Geometrically, complex conjugation corresponds to a reflection over the real axis in the complex plane. Thus, it is the map that sends a complex number $z = a + ib$ to the complex number $\bar{z} = a - ib$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$The conjugate of the RHS is $$\cos(x)-i\sin(x)=\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)=e^{-ix}$$